# GoDaddy Web Hosting with Angular and Microsoft Web API

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, ssl-certificate, web-hosting

I have purchased hosting with Go Daddy as well as an ssl cert for my domain. If I want to host a site using Angular for the front end and Microsoft Web Api for the back end, I believe that I need a sub domain, does this mean that I need to purchase a second SSL cert to host the API? Is there a way that both of these can be hosted on the same web site? This is for a simple personal site that I don't want to invest too much money into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Question *If I want to host a site using Angular for the front end and Microsoft Web Api for the back end, I believe that you need a sub domain*

-If your Angular application is developed using non-Microsoft Environment, Yes you will need two different endpoints. For this, the basic approach would be to use two different subdomains. And if that is the case,

You can purchase SSL wildcard certificate or certificate with subdomain support.

On the other hand, you always have an option to create web server then configure reverse proxy for both endpoints. On the latter approach your api endpoint can be :

```
<http(s)://mydomain.com/api/...>
```

and your site would be redirected to

```
<http(s)://mydomain.com/myBlog/...>
```

---

Alo Please Note That:  Microsoft .Net Core has implicit support for hosting both **Angular as front-end and .Net Core MVC as back-end** in the **Same Application**. You may consider to merge both project into Microsoft .Net Core Application

Comment: I would love to use the .net core approach, but the go daddy hosting environment doesn't support .net core. I would like to avoid spending any more on certs as this is just for my personal site, but if you have more information on how to setup the reverse proxy on go daddy windows environment, that could be the right direction.

Comment: you may want to [check this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2016/08/25/setup-iis-with-url-rewrite-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-real-world-apps/)

Comment: If you feel that this answer is helpful for you, please consider to upvote and/or mark it as answer so that the community can also benefit from it

Comment: I have accepted your answer, and will be trying this out over the weekend, if your answer is able to work with the Go Daddy servers, I will award the bounty.

Comment: Dmoore thank you. Whether you are using godaddy or not, you can configure it on IIS

Comment: The problem is I don't have direct access to IIS, they make you go through a secondary system that is in the background making changes to IIS, I believe this is because it is a shared IIS site. I will give this a try this weekend though and see how it works. Thank you again.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't been able to test this (due to freezing pipes and I getting sick), but have to keep up my end of the bounty deal. Bounty has been awarded. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: sure, I wish you good luck. If you need anything feel free to reply.